# How can I disable the right analog for the camera in the PS4 Bedrock Edition?

Tags: ps4, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My right analog is broken, so I tried to use a mouse for the camera and it worked! But the game is taking the analog and mouse input for the camera at the same time.

How can I disable the right analog for the camera?

Comment: How is it taking analog and mouse input at the same time if the analog stick is broken?

Comment: The analog is broken in a way where if you leave it centered is going to start moving slowly to the top. When I move the camera from left to right and vice versa the camera still moves to the top simultaneously because is also taking the controller analog input.